# Swift not calling class init method on CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cagradientlayer

I have an Objective-C subclass of 'CAGradientLayer' that overrides the '+ (CAGradientLayer *)layer' initializer.  It is correctly included in my `Bridging-Header`

```
#import "ONCGradientLayer.h"

@implementation ONCGradientLayer

+ (ONCGradientLayer *)gradientLayer {
    return [ONCGradientLayer layer];
}

+ (ONCGradientLayer *)layer {
    ONCGradientLayer * layer = [super layer];
    layer.colors = @[(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:1] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1 alpha:1] CGColor]];
    layer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    layer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1);
    return layer;
}
```

This all works as expected from Objective-C, by calling either `[ONCGradientLayer layer]` or `[ONCGradientLayer gradientLayer]`

When I try to call it from swift, I'm given a compiler warning that the method has been renamed `init`, so I must call `ONCGradientLayer()` This, however, does not work, and the overridden initializer is never called.

I can work around this by adding a differently named initializer :

```
+ (ONCGradientLayer *)swiftInit {
    return [ONCGradientLayer layer];
}
```

I can successfully called that in swift using `ONCGradientLayer.swiftInit()`

What is going on that prevents me from calling `ONCGradientLayer()` and getting the overridden initializer?

UPDATE : 
I can make the `ONCGradientLayer()` work by refactoring it to use the `init` method, though I'm still curious why the other approach does not work.

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.colors = @[(id)[DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:.1 alpha:1] CGColor]];
        self.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        self.endPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all about a Swift component called the [*Clang Importer.*](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/lib/ClangImporter) It is responsible for translating Objective-C method names into Swift method names (and vice versa).

The Clang Importer assumes that if an Objective C class has a class method with the same name as the class except for the prefix and the lowercasing, possibly extended by `with`, *it is a class factory method.*

It also assumes that a class factory method is the same effectively as the initializer whose name is constructed the same way, and *hides* the corresponding factory method completely, because with ARC there is no meaningful difference between the two.

> **EXAMPLE:** NSString has factory method `stringWithFormat:` and initializer `initWithFormat:`.
>
> Well, `string` is the same as NSString stripped of its prefix and lowercased; so the Clang Importer assumes that `stringWithFormat:` is a factory method. Moreover, it is constructed just like `initWithFormat:`, so the Clang Importer assumes they are effectively the same, and hides the former.
>
> Therefore you have to say `String(format:)`, meaning `String.init(format:)`, in Swift. [The Clang Importer also strips the `with`, but that's another story.] There is no `String.withFormat(_:)` (or similar) in Swift, matching Objective-C `stringWithFormat:`.

That is exactly the situation with your ONCGradientLayer and `gradientLayer`. Your class method follows the class factory method naming convention.  Therefore, thanks to the Clang Importer, if there is an `init` — and there is — then the class factory method is hidden. Therefore you have to call `init` instead, saying `ONCGradientLayer()` in Swift.

But you didn’t define `init` to return a modified ONCGradientLayer, so the result is a plain layer without your modifications.

If you don’t like that, you have two choices. And you already discovered what they are!

- Change the class factory name, to e.g. `makeGradientLayer`. (That is exactly what you did by supplying the name `swiftInit`.)
- Or, define `init` to return a ONCGradientLayer modified in the same way as you did in `layer`. (That is what you did too.)